# ng-change does not trigger function

Tags: angularjs

I've got an app that has two separate selects with bound properties.  I want the user to be able to change the selected option on either of the selects, which will trigger a function.  But the function will use the value of the selected option from BOTH of the selects to send to an $http call for database query.  Here are code snippets:

html:

```
<div class="yearFilter">
    <label>Working Year : </label>
    <select ng-model="filterYear" ng-options="year.code as year.code for year in filterYears | unique:'code'" ngclick="setWorkingData({{filterSport}},{{filterYear}})">
    </select>
</div>
<div class="sportFilter">
    <label>Working Sport : </label>
    <select ng-model="filterSport" ng-options="sport.code as sport.desc for sport in filterSports | unique:'code'" ngclick="setWorkingData({{filterSport}},{{filterYear}})"></select>
</div>
```

js:

```
var PermitsCtrl = function ($scope, $http) {
    var init = function() {
        $http({
            ...
        }).success(function(data) {
            ...
            setWorkingData($scope.filterYear,$scope.filterSport);
        }).error(function(error){
            ...
        });
    }
    var setWorkingData = function (year, sport) {
        $http({
            url ....
            ...
            data  : "action=2&year_code="+year+"&sport_code="+sport,
            ...
        }).success(function(data) {
            $scope.workingData = data.workingData;
        }).error(function(error) {
            ...
        });
    }
    init();
}
```

Upon loading the page, init() is being triggered successfully, which builds the select options and in turn triggers the setWorkingData() function correctly, which changes other values in the DOM accordingly, based on the values in the two selects (filterYear and filterSport) sent by the calling init() function.  All is good so far.  But changing the value in either select does not trigger the setWorkingData function.  The html that is rendered looks correct:

```
<select ng-model="filterYear" ng-options="year.code as year.code for year in filterYears | unique:'code'" ng-change="setWorkingData(15,FB)" class="ng-valid ng-dirty"><option value="0" selected="selected">14</option><option value="1" selected="selected">15</option></select>
```

When I change the selected option for either select in the browser, the parameter values for the setWorkingData() function are rendered correctly in the DOM for both selects, but the function is never triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setWorkingData()` is defined with private access in the controller. In order for it to be accessible from the view, it must be declared on the scope:

```
$scope.setWorkingData = setWorkingData;
```

BTW, you don't need `{{` `}}` for the arguments in `ng-change`/`ng-click`:

```
ng-change="setWorkingData(filterSport, filterYear)"
```